# Emacs - kill buffer without prompt

Tags: emacs

I'm wondering how it can be done, so Emacs doesn't pop the prompt asking me whether I really want to kill current buffer with *C-x k* shortcut.

Interesting thing is that same action done via toolbar kills buffer instantly without prompting the user. Any solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default, Emacs *doesn't* ask you if you want to kill the buffer.  It does ask you *which* buffer you want to kill.

If you don't want to be asked which buffer you want to kill, you can use this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") 'kill-this-buffer)
```

If you're being prompted for confirmation, then there's something in your .emacs (or the site specific initialziation).  Try running `emacs -q` to check Emacs w/out your .emacs.

*Note:* Verified with Emacs 23.2.

Comment: 'kill-this-buffer is part of emacs and that should be used instead.

Answer (score 11):

You can find out what that menu entry does with <kbd>C-h k</kbd> and then clicking on the entry. It turns out to be a command named *kill-this-buffer*.

Then you can bind that command to a key combination:

```
(global-set-key "\C-xk" 'kill-this-buffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (kill-buffer (buffer-name))))
```

Comment: Minor improvement: (kill-buffer (current-buffer))

Comment: Since c. Emacs 24.3 you can just (global-set-key "\C-xk" 'kill-this-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467002/how-to-kill-buffer-in-emacs-without-answering-confirmation

```
(defun volatile-kill-buffer ()
   "Kill current buffer unconditionally."
   (interactive)
   (let ((buffer-modified-p nil))
     (kill-buffer (current-buffer))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x k") 'volatile-kill-buffer)     ;; Unconditionally kill unmodified buffers.
```